# How to tune learning rate with HParams Dashboard

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard, hyperparameters, learning-rate

In Tensorflow [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard/hyperparameter_tuning_with_hparams), it is shown how to tune several hyperparameters but not the learning rate.I have searched how to tune learning rate using HParams dashboard but could not find much. The only example is another question on [github](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/34275) but it does not work.Can you please give me some suggestions on this?Should I use a callback function?Or provide different learning rates in hp_optimizer as in the question in github? Or something else?

Thank you,